# MockMvc: как отправить JSON как RequestPart?

Tags: java, json, mock

У меня есть контроллер, который принимает два RequestPart: JSON и MultipartFile:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/mail", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Report> mail(@RequestPart("data") MailMessageDto dto,
                                   @RequestPart(name = "attachments", required = false) List<MultipartFile> attachments,
                                   Locale locale) {
```

Пишу тесты, пока такие:

```
@Test
public void receiveAndSend() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(TEST_FILE, getOriginalFilename(),
            CONTENT_TYPE, new FileInputStream(new File(TEST_FILE_PATH)));
    String json = asJson(new MailMessageDto(TO, TITLE, CONTENT));
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = multipart(controllerMask)
            .file(multipartFile)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .content(json);
    result = mockMvc.perform(builder)
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    assertNull(result.getResponse().getErrorMessage());
}
```

Пишет:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = Required request part 'data' is not present
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Как мы видим, не задано имя RequestPart (хотя, мне кажется, проблема не только в этом). Подскажите, как правильно отправить JSON?